# How can I add destination filename with gz for AWS Firehose on S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a question similar to

[How can I set the destination filename for AWS Firehose on S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514613/how-can-i-set-the-destination-filename-for-aws-firehose-on-s3)

but I don't need dynamic naming: I just want to add .gz suffix to the filename

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Feature of dynamic naming with firehose is not there at this time of writing,

With dynamic naming it is not possible with firehose alone,

> S3 -- (create event trigger) Event Trigger -- Lambda

Code your lambda so that you can rename your file accordingly.
Renaming is creating a copy of the existing object. It is not just changing the name alone.

You can use your language of choice supported by lambda to do it. Optionally you can run a command line as a scheduled job.

Hope it helps.